# exit transition from activity not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have three activities (A, B and C) with an image view. Activity A has a small image view, B a mid-sized image view and C a fullscreen image view. From A to B I use
`makeSceneTransitionAnimation` for the transition. Start and Exit transition are working fine between A and B. From B to C I also use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation`. Thats is also working fine but when I go from C to B and then from B to A the exit transition is not working.

Is there some overriding process from C to B that affects the exit transition from B to A?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I am satisfied with for the moment.
My first approach was to monitor, inspect and manage the shared elements via `SharedElementCallback`but this does not seem to work as there are no shared elements in activity B when comming from C. So now when I am in activity B and I want to go to activity A, I check which activity I come from (A or C). Is it activity A then I simply use `supportFinishAfterTransition`. If I am coming from activity C I use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` to activity A. The second case creates a new instance of activity A. Thats why I just finish the older instance of activity A.

I uploaded my solution on github to the repo "transition" in case somebody wants to use some code (github account is linked here on stackoverflow).

If somebody knows a better solution please let me know.